# How to use EXPO INIT's View function in create-react-app?

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-app

I have created my project using `create-react-app` developed by the facebook community

How can I use code that works in `expo init` projects like using `View` `in create-react-app` projects:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Spalsh extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View></View>
        )
    }
}
```

because when trying to add this library `import {View} from "react-native";` run error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is create-react-app and another thing is expo. Expo is a module for react native ! And cra is a module developed by facebook using React for create web apps.

If u want build and APK or IOs app you must need react-native, for setting up the development environment follow the next tutorial https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: But using expo doesn't allow native code? Using this is not a cleaner way to create the create-react-app applications

Comment: No, expo allow a development of android or ios app more easy, the right way to develop in react-native is using CLI of RN.

Comment: In itself about the link that you shared ... I install following these steps, only in the type of projects start with create-react-app project_name and not expo init project_name

Comment: cra is for web apps while expo and react native is for apps mobiles

Comment: Whoops! I took a course and it was all based on create-react-app which I thought is the easiest way to take full control of my application. Thank you

Comment: The syntaxes of the both are very similar but they are not the same. u are welcome !